# How to update the facebook profile in my application if the user changes his facebook profile details after logging in?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an application which requires the user to login through Facebook. After getting the public details like username, email id, profile pic the same things are shown in the application in 'My Profile' page.

**Everything works fine. But a scenario**

- suppose the user changes his Facebook username through Facebook website or through Facebook application after logging in through
  Facebook in the client application .
- How the new username will reflect in his 'My Profile ' page as it
  will be showing the same old username? Does the Facebook SDK provides
  the method to automatically receive the public details when we go to
  the 'My Profile' page?

Comment: I think you have to create one function and call the function in ViewDidAppear(). And that function will be fetching User info from facebook graph API.

Comment: @AnuragSharma yes it is pretty clear. But please do tell which method we have to call in ViewDidAppear? Please post an answer i will surely support it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are already done with Login part, Now Call this function in the `ViewDidAppear()` to get User info:

```
func GetUserInfo(completionHandler handler: @escaping(_ response: [String: Any]) -> Void) {

if((FBSDKAccessToken.current()) != nil) { //If you have a valid Access token

    FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email"]).start( completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
        if (error == nil) {

            //everything works fine print the user data
            print(result ?? AnyObject.self)

            //Here you can get any type of information of user
            if let jsondata = result as? [String: Any], let strEmail = jsondata["email"] as? String, let fb_id = jsondata["id"] as? String, let picture = jsondata["picture"] as? [String: Any], let data = picture["data"] as? [String: Any],let url = data["url"] as? String  {

                print(url)
                print(strEmail)
                print(fb_id)


                handler(jsondata) //Pass the data in the completion Handler
            }


        } else {
            //failure popup
        }
    })
}

}
```